# How do I change every element in a vector to my reference class?

Tags: r

I am trying to convert every object in my vector of strings to a reference class. Suppose my reference class is:

```
myrefclass <- function(str) {
  methods <- list()

  methods$cnt <- function() {
    return(str_length(str))
  }

  methods
}
```

I tried to convert the following vectors (**albeit, no success**):

```
v1 <- c("ABC", "D", "FGHI")
v2 <- c(ABC="ABC", D="D", FGHI="FGHI")
```

Then I try to apply the reference class to each element of the vector:

```
res1 <- sapply(v1, myrefclass)
res2 <- sapply(v2, myrefclass)
```

I would then think I could use this as follows (**but regretfully it doesn't work**):

```
> res1["ABC"]$cnt
NULL
> res2["ABC"]$cnt
NULL
```

How do I create a vector of reference classes and access its methods?

> NOTE #1: I would prefer a base-R solution but it would be interesting to
>   see what packages might help
>
> NOTE #2: I am looking for a dynamic solution. To illustrate that point,
>   suppose an extension of this question would be to use `res1` or `res2`
>   to find all strings that have `$cnt=3`. Therefore, accessing strings
>   as in `res1$ABC$cnt` won't work as you don't know that `ABC` is in
>   `v1` or `v2` (whichever you think is appropriate).

Comment: If you want the number of characters, use `nchar`.

Comment: For clarification, you want `res1["ABC"]$cnt=3` and `res1["FGHI"]$cnt=4`. Is that it?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I would like to achieve

Comment: Call me surprised that this doesn't seem to be a simple question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer to this. My problem was that I **SHOULDN'T** create a vector of reference classes as it seems to mess up my objects and their corresponding methods, I **SHOULD** create a list:

```
v2 <- list(ABC="ABC", D="D", FGHI="FGHI")
res2 <- lapply(v2, myrefclass)
```

And then to lookup the length of a particular string I would do:

```
res2[["ABC"]]$cnt()
[1] 3
res2[["FGHI"]]$cnt()
[1] 4
```

Voila!